# MYSQL: Getting a 1 or 0 query result in a table based on whether a value is in second table

Tags: mysql

I want to get a list of all my users and mark the ones that also appear in another table named memo (based on their unique identifiers) if a certain row value is 16. Each row of the mp table has a worker and a memo. The worker is the unique user id. So a user is in a memo (say 16) if u.keyid = mp.worker and mp.memo = 16. This is the query I wrote.

```
SELECT DISTINCT  
            u.name AS name,
            IF ((mp.worker = u.keyid AND mp.memo = 16),1,0) AS isin
        FROM users AS u, mp;
```

So isin should be 1 if there is an entry in table mp such that mp.worker = u.keyid for the memo 16.

However this query gets me a complete list of users with all 0 And all the users (again) that were in the memos with a 1. So say The users are John, Michael, Sarah and Jane. Say only John and Jane were in the meeting I get this result:

```
John       0
Micahel    0
Sarah      0
Jane       0
John       1
Jane       1
```

But what I want is:

```
John       1
Micahel    0
Sarah      0
Jane       1
```

How should I write it to get what I want?

Comment: You query appears to work but in fact you dont have an INNER JOIN but a cartesian one,because if the conditions for INNER JOIN are there, you get 1 but for all those other values you get 0.Just use a proper JOIN not in the IIF clause

Comment: Can you give me an example? Because without the IF how do I get the value of the column isin? How do I get the 1 or zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is doing a `CROSS JOIN` (cartesian product).

You just need an `EXISTS` clause (this may also be done with a `left join`, but I think `EXISTS` is clearer)

```
SELECT u.Name
       CASE WHEN EXISTS (Select null from mp
                         where mp.worker = u.keyid
                         and   mp.memo = 16)
            THEN 1 else 0 END
       AS isin
FROM users u
```

You can of course use an `IF` clause instead of the `CASE... WHEN` (which is ANSI, while `IF` is not)